# Grails 2.3+ looking for jar in local maven repo for **plugin**

Tags: maven, grails, plugins, jar, zip

Okay, after a solid day I've solved my problem but think this MUST be a bug.  I started in grails 2.3.2 and upgraded to 2.3.4, all the same

My grails app is divided up into plugin: a base plugin that has core domain objects and some interfaces, N "factory" plugins that require the base plugin and one app, that can include any number of the "factory" plugins.  All of these plugins, for now, are local (not in any external maven repo)

So this is what people are calling the 'transitive' plugin issue.  What I'm seeing is that I write the base plugin and use 'maven install' to put it into my local repo (the ~/.m2/repository...).  Fine.  Then I write one of the "factory" plugins where in the BuildConfig under the 'plugins' section I put the 'base' plugin.  It compiles and packages fine, but when I run 'maven-install' it says:

> | Error Could not find artifact pkg-blah:name-blah:jar:ver-blah in
>   grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (scope: compile)
>   (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

Now, beyond the s there's something I didn't see for about 6 hours.  The ***'jar'***. See it there?  I didn't for a LONG time.  A very LONG, frustrating time. Why is it looking for 'jar' when it's been put into the 'plugins' section of the BuildConfig?  That, to my understanding, is only when it's in the 'dependencies' section.

I think that's the bug.  Let me know how wrong I may or may not be.  Dunno.  I'm no Grails God, just an everyday user.

Oh, the fix:  use grails create-pom, put 'pom true' into the BuildConfig, then edit the pom and under the dependencies section of the pom for the plugins, add in `<type>zip</type>`. Oh, default packaging at the top of the pom is 'grails-plugin' or something.  Change it to 'zip'.  Then all is fine.

Just dunno why it's defaulting to 'jar' for a plugin.  Edify me!

Comment: This looks like an edge case with plugins in the latest version of Grails - not exactly the sort of thing SO is good for. You should discuss this on the User mailing list and create an issue at http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS

Comment: Will, could you share the bug ID please?

Comment: This is really a big issue for me (we are using many plugins) I have created the issue: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10943 If the issue is duplicate, please link it with your issue.

Comment: This is fixed in version 2.3.5