# How to release and reference Grails plugins using local Maven repository

Tags: maven, grails, dependencies

Summary

I create two plugins A and B with Grails 2.3.4 where B is a plugin used by A plugin. I get error when I use A plugin in my application.

Details

When I run the following command, for plugin B, it successfully release the plugin to local maven repository. I can see it in the ~/.m2/... folder.

```
~plugin-b: grails maven-install
```

Then I add a reference to plugin B with plugin A, so I add the reference to BuildConfig in plugin A:

```
plugins {
    compile "com.test.plugins:b:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
}
```

Now, I think, I should be able to run the next command and the plugin should be released to the local maven repository but I get the error instead:

```
~plugin-a: grails maven-install
| Plugin packaged grails-a-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.zip
| Generating POM file.....
| Error Could not find artifact com.test.plugins:b:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT (scope: compile) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| POM generated: //dependencies/dependencies_A_plugin/target/pom.xml...
Maven install complete.
```

Here is the generated POM file:

```
 // pom header
 <artifactId>a</artifactId>
  <packaging>zip</packaging>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>A</name>
  <description>Brief summary/description of the plugin.
</description>
  <url>http://grails.org/plugin/a</url>
  <developers>
    <developer>
      <name>Your name</name>
    </developer>
  </developers>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.test.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>b</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    ... just ending tags
```

Actually, also plugin A has been released to the local Maven repository, but it is probably corrupted, because when I create a Grails application and add a reference to A plugin into BuildConfig, then I am not even able to start up that application.

```
~ grails
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact com.test.plugins:b:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error Could not find artifact com.test.plugins:b:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

So, the application has found A plugin, but not the B plugin, which is referenced by A plugin. To me, it seems there is an issue with generated POM file in the local Maven repository for the A plugin. There is probably missing:

```
  <type>zip</type>
```

But I have not found a way how to add the type to that dependency.

Anyone able to help?

Comment: I just found this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20416253/grails-2-3-looking-for-jar-in-local-maven-repo-for-plugin that is probably about the same issue.

Comment: I had problems with the maven resolver, what happens if you switch to Ivy?

Comment: I think it would probably work. But I have to use Maven. The solution is to generate POM file in the Grails plugin and then add zip type manually. Also, I have reported this issue http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10943

Comment: This is fixed in version 2.3.5